# student A has a 0.85 chance to solve problem, student B has a 0.9 chance to solve the problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A - has a 0.85 chance to solve a problem
B - has a 0.9 chance to solve a problem

1) find the probability that the problem will be solved if A and B try to solve it independently of each other.

2) find the probability that both students will solve the problem if they are solving it independently.

3) if the problem was solved by one student, find the probability that it was student A that solved the problem.

---

S - the event that the problem got solved
For 1) we have:
$P\left(S\right)=P\left(AB^c\right)+P\left(A^cB\right)+P\left(AB\right)=98.5\%$

For 2) we have
$P(AB)=76,5\%$

For 3) wouldn't it just be $P(AB^C)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $3^{rd}$  Case will amount to: $$P(AB^C|AB^C+BA^C)$$
 This means to  show that favourable outcome is that only A solves the problem: $0.85*0.1$

And total such probablity when only one person solved the problem:$0.85*0.1+0.9*0.15$

Thus your probablity comes out to be$$\frac{0.085}{0.085+0.135}=\frac{17}{44}$$
Hope it solves your problem now?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? is it the probability of A that is tied to the probability that the problem was solved by exactly one student?

Comment: @SiezeTheMeansOfProduction , Please see the edit